# Custom ASP.NET Server Control in Toolbox of Project Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've developed some custom asp server controls and they all work how I need.

I'm now looking to create a Project Template in Visual Studio that includes these custom controls. The problem I'm having is adding them to the toolbox.

The template contains the references to the custom control dll's and they are registered in the appropriate pages - but they do not appear in the toolbox.

Is it possible to automatically include the controls in the Visual Studio toolbox so that a user can drag and drop them on to a form? If I enter them in the source view by coding them they work fine and appear in design view, but I need drag and drop functionality. Preferably without having to Right Click >> Choose Items

Thanks